# How to sample from a Burr-Type XII distribution in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, sampling

I'm need to sample from a Burr-Type XII distribution with zero mean and unit variance in Python. In scipye there is `scipy.stats.burr12` which seems the right thing to use. However, it is not clear to me how to set the parameters c, d, loc and scale in order to make the distribution to have zero mean and unit variance.

I have tried setting c=1 and d=2.1, computed the mean and the variance with `mean,var=burr12.stats(c,d,moments='mv')` and tried to rescale the samples with `x=(burr12.rvs(c,d)-mean)/np.sqrt(var)`. However, if I make an histogram with 1000 such random samples, it doesn't look to have a 0 mean and unit variance.

How should I set c, d, loc and scale in order to have samples with zero mean and unit variance?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to rephrase a little bit. The problem is how to set the parameters of scipy.stats.burr12 in order to have samples with zero mean and unit variance.

Answer (score 0):

> How should I set c, d, loc and scale in order to have samples with zero mean and unit variance?

First, I'll answer the question "How should I set c, d, loc and scale in order for the *distribution* to have zero mean and unit variance?"

In short, use `root` to solve for the parameters you need.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize, stats

# Assuming these are fixed
c = 1
d = 2.1

def f(x):
  # when loc and scale are right, this function will return [0, 0]
  loc, scale = x
  mean, var = stats.burr12.stats(c, d, loc=loc, scale=scale, moments='mv')
  return [mean, var - 1]

res = optimize.root(f, [0, 1])
loc, scale = res.x
dist = stats.burr12(c, d, loc=loc, scale=scale)
dist.stats(moments='mv')
# (0.0, 0.9999999999999998)
```

You can confirm that the PDF and histogram of random variates agree with one another closely.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(loc, loc + 1, 300)
plt.plot(x, dist.pdf(x), label='pdf')

rvs = dist.rvs(size=10000000)
plt.hist(rvs, bins=np.linspace(loc, loc+1, 100), 
         density=True, label='histogram')

plt.xlim(x[0], x[-1])
plt.title("Burr 12 Histogram vs PDF")
```

[image]

The slight excess in the histogram is explained by the fact that the histogram is normalized over [0, 1] rather than [0, oo].

Nonetheless, the *sample* mean and *sample* variance are not exactly what you expected.

```py
np.mean(rvs)  # -0.00024686599935315023
np.std(rvs, ddof=1)  # 0.69110486803508
```

This is unavoidable unless you can draw an infinitely large sample. The distribution is heavy-tailed, so there are some rare but extremely large values that increase the variance when considering the whole population, but the sample variance you observe will tend toward smaller values.

Beyond that, you'd need to make some decisions about what you mean for the samples to have zero mean and unit variance, since they follow distributions. If you want them to be exactly 0 and 1 every time, you could subtract the sample mean from the sample and divide by the sample standard deviation.